# $.each() doesn't work when only one item to loop over?

Tags: jquery, getjson, each

I had an each method call on some `getJSON` results:

```
    if(data && data.query && data.query.results)
    {                
        $.each(data.query.results.span, function(i, item)
        {
            console.log("Content:" + item.content); // FAILS --> UNDEFINED!!
         });
    }
```

I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't display anything even though I could see JSON returning a single result.

So I removed each and did this:

```
    if(data && data.query && data.query.results)
    {
            console.log("Content:" + data.query.results.span.content); // WORKS!!
    }
```

Now it works.

**Is there no way to use `each()` when there is only a single result?**

Answer (score 8):

`$.each`  expects an array in the first argument, so something like this:

```
$.each([ data.query.results.span ], function(i, item) { ... }
```

should work. The square brackets create a single item array.

Answer (score 1):

If the first argument of `$.each()` is not an array, then it will iterate over the properties (for lack of a better term) of the object.

For instance:

```
var a = {first: "abc", second: "def"};
$.each(a, function(i, item){...});
```

The function passed into `$.each` will be called twice.  The first time, i will be "first" and item will be "abc".  The second time i will be "second" and item will be "def".

Answer (score 0):

Doublecheck the collection first, if it is already an array of objects.
If not, overwrite your variable nested in itself as an array of objects:

```
if (MyCollection[0]==undefined) MyCollection = [MyCollection];
$.each(MyCollection, function (key,item) { ....
```